# Problem with Swagger in Spring (error with dependencies)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger, springfox

SwaggerConfig.java

```java
package com.platzi.market.web.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.platzi.market.web.controller"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

If I remove @Configuration the error is removed but it doesn't work, because it opens the swagger but I get a browser alert that says ''Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually"

I don't know how to expose all the code, I leave you the dependencies of the build.gradle document

dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    runtimeOnly'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I also tried another version 3.0.0 but the same thing happens to me. So I attach an image of the error with both annotations

```
Error: "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiListingScanner' defined in URL jar:file:/C:/Users////"
```

Comment: What version of spring boot and gradle are you using?

Comment: I suggest migrate to open api:https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Comment: Gradle 7.4 ,  Spring 3.0.6